# Finding a line that is orthogonal to other 2 lines and intersects them?

Tags: vector-spaces

The lines given below are skew. Find parametric equations for the line which
intersects them both orthogonally.

$l1 : x = 6 + 2t; y = -1 + t; z = -5 - 2t$

$l2 : x = 8 - 5t; y = -1 + 2t; z = 3 - t$

So I found the vector that orthogonal to both lines are $(1,4,3)$ using the cross product. Now how do I find the line that is in this directio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take an arbitary point of $l1$ (depending on $t$) and check if the line containing this point with the direction $(1,4,3)$ intersects the line $l2$. This will be the case for only one t.

This $t$ gives you the desired point on $l1$.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the cross-product as you did gives the vector $<3,12,9>=3<1,4,3>$, so the line we want is parallel to the vector $<1,4,3>$.

Taking a general vector from a point on line 2 to a point on line 1 gives
$<-2+2t+5s,t-2s,-8-2t+s>$, so setting $<-2+2t+5s,t-2s,-8-2t+s>=k<1,4,3>$ yields
$7t+22s=8$ and $8t+14s=-2$ (or, equivalently, $4t+7s=-1$).

Now you can solve for s and t to find a point on line 1 (or line 2) which the line we want passes through, and use the vector $<1,4,3>$ as a direction vector for the line.